# How to pop up a window on the windows login screen

Tags: windows, authentication, window, screen

I am writing a application to monitor some event. When the event comes, the pc is showing the login screen (you see this screen when you press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> ). Is it possible for me to show a window on the login screen when I got the event?

Answer (score 1):

In case any one run into this problem , I put my solution here.

I think I have made it possisble by injecting a dll to the winlogon.exe proccess.The dll can start a thread and pop up a window.

Maybe there is a better solution ...